# How can I refresh my local database from a web service when an item isn't found?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

The project I am working on involves a database and a web service for the source of data. This question, and I have several, is based on the idea that if I enter in a product number in `textBox1`, I want to see if the number is already in the database, if not I want to have it run my written code that goes to a web service and grabs the data and then updates the database.

1. What code should I use to check if the Product_ID is null or empty
2. What code do I need to write so that if the Product_ID is null or empty it will invoke the code I have already written that grabs data from a web service?

My linq code is:

```
Test_Data_ClassDataContext db = new Test_Data_ClassDataContext();
            var q = from p in db.Product_Masters
                    where p.Product_ID.Equals(textBox1.Text)
                    select p;
```

stealing from others ideas I am trying to test for null if null run the web service code if not null send it to datagridview for display.

```
If (q == null)
{
    Somehow call the other code so it takes textBox1 and get the data from the service
}

else
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = q;
}
```

Background: I am a newbie to c#, once upon a time I played with vb6 and so to me c# is not only like learning a new language but also learning to walk again, not to mention I was never a good vb6 programmer.

Comment: the reason I am moving your background information to the bottom is so that the problem information displays in the question summary on the questions page.  Your background info doesn't really help the reader to know whether they can answer the question while the summary might.

Comment: How you call a service from a client depends on what type of service it is. Can you add some details about the service you want to call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because linq to sql uses defered execution until `GetEnumerator()` is called you need to fist invoke your query.

```
var result = q.ToList();

if (result.Count == 0)
{
  //Somehow call the other code so it takes textBox1 and get the data from the service
}
else
{
  dataGridView1.DataSource = result;
}
```

Now that you have invoked the query you can simply check if there are results, if not you can simply call your webservice.

Answer (score 8):

q will never be null.

The value of a query expression is *an object representing the query*. It is not *the results of the query*.

If what you want to know is "does this query have any results" then say "q.Any()".

Answer (score 0):

What you also want to know is: "how do i call a webservice?".

This is a topic onto itself:
In VS this is made easy by adding the service reference (either a Web Service Reference for ASMX services or a Service Reference for a WCF service).

I suggest Googling for info on either subjects and how to tell them apart.

Comment: Actually I have that code written and working, but what I don't know is the c# way of calling that code. In my case if the record doesn't exist, I want it to run the other code I have written.

Comment: I am flabbergasted that you claim to have a written and working call to a webservice (which I don't contest) but you are then somehow unable to fit that into the above if statement..

Comment: Well in fact it took 2 weeks and some help from someone to help correct my errors. The reason I stated I had working code, was so that my true question didn't become irrelevant by virtue of the subject changing to talk of code for a web service. I wasn't expecting folks to become upset by my basic of basic question and hence the original title, "Another of my newbie questions". Some folks don't have time for newbies and I understand that. So I am sorry I flabbergasted you. My only intent was to ask a simple question.

Comment: Well, I didn't mean to come off as mean or anything. Kudo's for learning and all that. Perhaps you can post what you have for calling the webservice and then we can see how to fit the pieces?